# Haskell function finding all maps between elements of two lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinatorics

I am struggling with coding a Haskell function which given two lists (A and B) returns a list of all mappings **Fi: A --> B** where a single mapping is represented as a list of pairs. The function header would be:

```
findAllMappings :: [a] -> [b] -> [[(a, b)]]
```

For example, after running the function for two lists like below:

```
findAllMappings [1, 2] ["A", "B"]
```

I would expect an output like:

```
[
    [(1, "A"), (2, "A")],
    [(1, "B"), (2, "B")],
    [(1, "A"), (2, "B")],
    [(1, "B"), (2, "A")],
]
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: What did you try? We're totally into helping you fix a broken attempt. But you're in charge of doing the first burst of effort, not us.

Comment: Think about a formula for the expected length of your main resulting list. You might find function `sequence` useful. Also [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) is your friend and can take either a function name or a type signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is clearly homework and you didn't make an attempt, I'm not going to spoil the whole solution, but here's some hints to get you started:

First, create a helper function with type `a -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`. As part of not spoiling the whole solution, I'm not telling you what this should do, but between its type and how I use it below, you should be able to figure it out.

Second, given that helper, it's trivial how you'd write your function for a known list length. Here it is for lengths 0-3:

```
findAllMappings [] bs = [[]]
findAllMappings [a0] bs = [[ab0] | ab0 <- helper a0 bs]
findAllMappings [a0, a1] bs = [[ab0, ab1] | ab0 <- helper a0 bs, ab1 <- helper a1 bs]
findAllMappings [a0, a1, a2] bs = [[ab0, ab1, ab2] | ab0 <- helper a0 bs, ab1 <- helper a1 bs, ab2 <- helper a2 bs]
```

But clearly you can't just do this for your final answer, since you need to handle lists of arbitrary length, and you can't do that with a case for each length. So study what this is doing, and think of a way you can use a recursive function to do it.

---

As an alternative approach, figure out a function like this (hint: `base` already has it, so you don't need to write it):

```
f 0 ["A", "B"] = [[]]
f 1 ["A", "B"] = [["A"], ["B"]]
f 2 ["A", "B"] = [["A", "A"], ["A", "B"], ["B", "A"], ["B", "B"]]
```

And then find a way to attach the elements from the first list passed to `findAllMappings` to the appropriate result of it (hint: `base` already has functions for this too).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. For the record no homework involved !